# Using jacoco with Gradle

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin

Jacoco fails to generate a code coverage report if the tests fail.

Below is the relevant section of my gradle file:

```
task unitTest(type: Test) {
    forkEvery = 1
    jvmArgs = ['-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true']
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
    exclude '**/**TestBase.*'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    ignoreFailures = true
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

task functionalTest(type: Test) {
    forkEvery = 1
    jvmArgs = ['-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true']
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.functionalTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.functionalTest.runtimeClasspath
    exclude '**/**TestBase.*'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }  
}


jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."

    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
    }   
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/test.exec')
}
```

Even though I have specified the "ignoreFailures=true", there is no code coverage report after the test run.

```
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///unitTest/index.html
:MYModule:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 41 mins 34.018 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the executionData was pointing to a wrong "test.exec". It should have been "unitTest.exec", named after the test task that was being executed.